# Fragment not completely inflating

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I've created an Activity that has three tabs. On clicking Tab 1 it opens up a fragment (TaskFragment) containing two buttons, each with an associated text.

When I click on the "Create Appraisal Report" button it properly inflates another Fragment's (AppraisalReportFragment) two text lines (that now supercede the previous two), and a page title (Appraisal Reports), but the two initial buttons remain in place.

I'm trying to get everything on the initial Fragment to be changed over to an entirely new Fragment, with it's own buttons and text), but right now only some of these changes take place.

**TaskFragment**

```
package usjersey.com.jerseyscore.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import usjersey.com.jerseyscore.R;

/**
 * Created by dhiggins on 11/20/2017.
 */

public class TasksFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "TasksFragment";

    Intent intent;
    private RelativeLayout layoutToAdd;


//    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);
        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, null);
        //layoutToAdd = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.TaskFragment);

        Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_create_appraisal_rpt);
        ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AppraisalReportFragment appraisalRptAct = new AppraisalReportFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


                //fragmentTransaction.setTransition(fragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                //Fragment newFragment = new AppCompatDialogFragment();
                //FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tasks_page_fragment, appraisalRptAct);

                //transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        Button ID2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_check_in_for_today);
        ID2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TasksFragment checkInForToday = new TasksFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.herds_check_in_for_today_fragment4, checkInForToday);

                //fragmentTransaction.setTransition(fragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                //Fragment newFragment = new AppCompatDialogFragment();
                //FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                //transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        /*rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AppraisalReportActivity.class);
                final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_create_appraisal_rpt);
            }
        });*/

        return rootView;
    }

    /*public void buttonOnClick(View v){

    }*/
}
```

**fragment_tasks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tasks_page_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- First A -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="onCreateView"
        android:text="@string/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- First B -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_appraisal_rpt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="onCreateView"
        android:text="@string/btn_create_appraisal_report"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- First B-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:text="@string/tasks_check_day_score"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <!-- First B-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_create_appraisal_rpt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/tasks_print_email_regmail"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>


**AppraisalReportFragment**

package usjersey.com.jerseyscore.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import usjersey.com.jerseyscore.R;

/**
 * Created by dhiggins on 11/29/2017.
 */

public class AppraisalReportFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "Appraisal Report";
        TextView textView;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container, false);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_appraisal_report, container, false);
                TextView output = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                //output.setText("Frag 2");
                return view;
        }
}
```

**fragment_appraisal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tasks_page_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appraisal_report"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/btn_all_cows_in_herd"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cows_scored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="onCreateView"
        android:text="@string/btn_cows_scored"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_check_in_for_today"
        android:text="@string/label_all_cows_in_herd_report"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_cows_scored"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/label_checked_scored_cows"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appraisal_report"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/title_appraisal_reports"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your frame Layouts,you need to have only one frame layout so that you replace everything when button is clicked

Comment: can you share xml file of your activity @Dave Higgins

Comment: Thanks, Dheeraj. Hmm. So unlike a traditional web page that's a separate component connected to other separate web pages via hyperlinks Android's designed to have everything within single activities?
 In other words if say three fragments (A, B, and C) were to be available within an activity to be displayed singly the View structure would be something like- Activity layout/ Fragment Layout A/ Fragment A...Fragment Layout B/ Fragment B...Fragment Layout C/ Fragment C? So during operation Fragment B's id would be used by say Fragment C to overwrite/replace it?

Comment: This forum seems a bit limited for adding any code here. I'd previously placed my related code (TaskFragment.java and its associated fragment_tasks.xml) and the fragment to overwrite/replace TaskFragment (AppraisalReportFragment.java + fragment_appraisal.xml) is shown earlier in my post- if that helps.

Comment: added tags, improved headers, gave some space to the initial paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inflate your fragment you should setVisibility to `gone` to your buttons from the previous layout after committing the FragmentManager's transaction in your activity

You can do it like this and then change them to `visible` again when returning

```
b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Change the names of the buttons according to your code

Comment: Thank you. Setting the button to GONE did the trick. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, man, the answer solved your issue, if you consider it's not enough , well....

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you don't know how to mark the question as accepted ? I understood you didn't consider it as accepted but now I feel I misunderstood you(

Comment: Correct on the not knowing how to select "accepted." I see now that appears to be done by clicking on the check icon, which then turns green. Thanks again.